# Use stack layout with Android-Xamarin + MvvmCross

Tags: c#, android-layout, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm new to Android-Xamarin.. and MvvmCross and I've read some basic samples that bind a ObservableCollection (defined in a ViewModel) to a ListView in a .xaml layout, so each element of the ObservableCollection will be loaded "automatically".

But, instead of a vertical layout (top-down), I want my items to be shown using a stack Layout [like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuu0c.png)

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thanks! A lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make your listview's data template contain a stacklayout with orientation horizontal. Something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
     <!--TODO CODE-->
    </StackLayout>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the Orientation tag to the stack layout tag

```
Orientation="Horizontal"
```